# Member groups different for subscriptions?

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

I'm migrating away from CartThrob/Subscriptions because it is essentially defunct (they terminated their Subscriptions product).

We've purchased DevDemon Subscriptions, and I'm starting to implement it.  I have a client's website that has a subscription service that offers access to various RSS feeds based on their subscription level.

I like the way the Actions are set up, but there doesn't appear to be a way to change what is done depending on the subscription?  For instance, if people subscribe to XXXX, we want to change their member group to one that allows access to a particular RSS feed page.

If they have a subscription to YYYY, we want to change their member group to a DIFFERENT group, which has access to different RSS feeds.

It unfortunately has to be done this way because third party products like iTunes can use the simple http auth to access RSS feeds, and we can set up group-based permissions for them in EE, but they can't load web pages to parse EE tags, etc.

From what I can see in Subscriptions, there's no way for us to do this, correct?  All I'd want is the ability to specify a different set of triggers for each subscription.

Comment: Hi khalwat - I have a custom extension that takes care of this if you are still looking for an answer. Email me chad at clearfirestudios dot com.

Answer (score 0):

Previous version only allowed you to change to one member group. This has since been changed and plans can have their own action to change to different member groups.

Comment: I sent an email to your support staff (the same as my posting here).  Hopefully that'll do it?